# Bijectivity of the composition of two bijective transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Say I have two linear transformations A,B:

$A: R^n\rightarrow R^m, B: R^m\rightarrow R^p$

If both A and B are bijective, can I deduce $BA: R^n\rightarrow R^p$ is also bijective?

Comment: Have you learnt about composition of injective functions and composition of surjective functions?

Comment: No, I just thought this should be the case intuitively but my grade for reduced for suggesting this.

Comment: What is your definition of bijective linear transformation? The exercise may want you to prove it from the 1st principle without relying on those proved facts.